# Send a Cookie in a RestAngular request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, cookies, restangular

I got a Restangular.getAll function,

when i call it the cookies are not included in the API request, unlike the HTML requests who gots.

if I force a:

```
Restangular.setDefaultHeaders({ Cookie: function() { return "foo " + $cookies.get('foo'); } })
```

The error is:

```
Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"
```

If I add to app.config:

```
RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({
    withCredentials: true
});
```

The error is:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [*link*] A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true.
 Origin [*host*] is therefore not allowed access. 
The credentials mode of an XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Please note that *host* and *link* are the abbreviations for page link and host link.

**EDIT:**
My CORSFilter in Spring:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

    public CORSFilter() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, authorization, content-type");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29696406/restangular-how-to-read-cookie-and-add-to-headers-at-each-query

Answer (score 0):

Your server has to return a particular content for Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
You could give your webapp host URL there, or dynamically copy the origin information (for development purposes).

NOTE: its a server side fix

Comment: it seems that with other pages you are not using withCredentials:true